# Why MySQL query returning null when a user doesn't have submissions?

Tags: mysql, database, group-by

I've got the following tables:

`submissions`:

```
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| title       | varchar(255)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| slug        | varchar(255)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description | mediumtext                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id     | int(11)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created     | datetime                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| type        | enum('tip','request')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| thumbnail   | varchar(36)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| removed     | tinyint(1) unsigned                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| keywords    | varchar(255)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ip          | int(10) unsigned                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`users`:

```
+----------------+------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field          | Type                   | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+----------------+------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id             | int(10) unsigned       | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| email          | varchar(128)           | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| hash           | varchar(64)            | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| salt           | varchar(32)            | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| username       | varchar(23)            | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| name           | varchar(32)            | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| about          | varchar(255)           | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| created        | datetime               | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| last_login     | timestamp              | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
| created_ip     | int(10) unsigned       | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| last_login_ip  | int(10) unsigned       | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| remember_me    | tinyint(3) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| photo          | varchar(36)            | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| confirmed      | tinyint(1) unsigned    | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| confirm_code   | varchar(64)            | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| public_profile | tinyint(1)             | NO   |     | 1                 |                             |
+----------------+------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

`submissions_comments`:

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id       | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| submission_id | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| comment       | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_id     | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created       | datetime         | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created_ip    | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| helpful_count | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| deleted       | tinyint(4)       | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And finally my query which returns the count of the submissions (tips and requests), and comments along with all info about the user:

```
SELECT a.*, sc.user_id,
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN b.type = "tip" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS "tipsCount",
COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN b.type = "request" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0) AS "requestsCount", COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT sc.id),0) as "commentsCount"
FROM users as a
LEFT JOIN submissions as b ON a.id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN submissions_comments as sc
ON a.id = sc.user_id WHERE a.username = ?
AND b.removed = 0
GROUP BY a.id, sc.user_id
LIMIT 1;
```

And this query works if the user has submitted a tip or request, but otherwise returns NULL. Am I doing a wrong group by or something?

EDIT:

sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c56a

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: `b.removed = 0` is creating the statement to return null when there are no `Submissions`. I you want a full solution please provide a fiddle and a desired result set.

Comment: @georstef added sqlfiddle above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still not sure what you need so I give you this query which returns Tips, Requests and Comments for a specific user:

```
SELECT 
  users.id,
  SUM(CASE WHEN submissions.type = "tip" then 1 else 0 END) as tips,
  SUM(CASE WHEN submissions.type = "request" then 1 else 0 END) as requests,
  (select count(*) 
   from submissions_comments 
   where submissions_comments.user_id = users.id) as comments
FROM 
  users
LEFT JOIN 
  submissions ON submissions.user_id = users.id 
             AND submissions.removed = 0
WHERE
  users.username = 'amc123' 
group by
  users.id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/825cb/17) example

Comment: This is exactly it! Thank you so much :D. It seems the key was the second select as well as the removed=0 like you previously mentioned. Much appreciated @georstef.